# How to drag and drop items in grid for angularjs and material design?

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, material-design

I am new with angular. I am trying to do a grid with angularjs and material design. Do you have an example to drag and drop the grid items?

Comment: Which grid specifically? What have you tried? Show us a code sample so we can help out!

Comment: This is my prototype: https://6b2613d30c559fbd74420d732318e1fa32ad627e-www.googledrive.com/host/0B664c2wv0masalRpZVNwREVPS00/